# Possible to make a task scheduler for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scheduled-tasks

I want to make an app where I can have a task (GET URL) run at predefined times (selectable in UI). For instance, Monday to Friday at 8am.

Is this possible in iOS?

I tried searching but haven't found anything very useful, probably using the wrong search terms. Does anyone happen to find some sample code for what I'm trying to do?

Edit: Pointing out that I want the app to perform these tasks even if the app is not running. I want to user to just select wanted days of the week and time, and then the phone will take care of everything - even if the phone is restarted.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to regularly wake up to download content, you can register to get push notifications, and download based on the contents of the notification. You are likely to get some cycles to do this close to the scheduled time.  If you want to 'opportunistically' download content you can register for background 'fetch' but there is no guarantee of scheduling.

See
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: But we can't run any task when the push notification is received right ? only when user taps on push notification. App can open then we can run. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all, the app has to be open for any kind of task to run. After that, there are 2 ways you can do it:

You can set a timer with a selector, or you can use grand central dispatch. Both have their strengths and weaknesses depending on what the task is...

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/index.html

check out those links and see if they can help.

Remember that you should do stuff like this on a background thread, and that the UI cannot be updated from any thread by the main thread. Additionally, remember the limitations iOS puts on background applications.

Comment: So it's not possible to do this when the app is not running? I want it to happen even if the app isn't in the background (meaning, even if the phone have been restarted)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
You can use -

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myFunc:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```